# No me elimina imagen de la carpeta

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, imagen

alguien sabe porque no me elimina la imagen de la carpeta?, me elimina el registro de la base de datos, pero no la imagen de la carpeta, envio mi codigo:

HTML

```html
<td>
  <form method="POST" action= {{action('vehiculosController@destroy', $listado->id)}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('¿Esta Seguro?')">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  </button>
  </form>
</td>
```

CONTROLLER

```js
public function destroy($id) {
  $vehiculo = Vehiculos::find($id);
  Storage::delete($vehiculo - > img_p_circulacion);
  $vehiculo - > delete();

  return redirect() - > route('vehiculos.index');
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: LA VISTA ESTA POR UN FOREACH!e IMG_P_CIRCULACION es la columna donde guarda la ruta de la imagen

Comment: La ruta que tienes en img_p_circulacion es absoluta o relativa?

Comment: perdon, soy nuevo en esos terminos, si me los pudieras explicar por favor....

Comment: qué es lo que tiene la variable **img_p_circulacion**? Imprime un ejemplo con un echo o un var_dump y agregalo a tu pregunta por favor

Comment: hay subi una imagen del registro de la base de datos amigo

Comment: Y si defines explicitamente el lugar del que lo quieres borrar? **Storage::disk('public')->delete($vehiculo -> img_p_circulacion);**

Comment: lo hice recien, y tampoco me elimina la imagen :c

Comment: Otra opción es utilizar la función unlink: **unlink($vehiculo -> img_p_circulacion)**

Comment: me da error, Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::unlink

Comment: Storage::disk('public')->unlink($vehiculo->img_p_circulacion);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las posibles causas que pienso pueden generar este error son:

> 1) la imagen no existe o la ruta está mal.
>
> 2) no tienes los permisos suficientes sobre la carpeta en donde estás
>   guardando los archivos.
>
> 3) ya se borró y no te diste cuenta...

Para el primer punto lo primero que tienes que asegurarte es a través de un var_dump o un echo **asegurarte** de que $vehiculo->img_p_circulación **sí trae la ruta o nombre correcto** antes de intentar el delete. Te recomiendo intentar dos cosas: Utilizar la función [unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) de php

```
public function destroy($id) {
  $vehiculo = Vehiculos::find($id);
  unlink(storage_path('app/media/imagenes/'.$vehiculo -> img_p_circulacion));
  $vehiculo -> delete();
  return redirect() -> route('vehiculos.index');
}
```

En ella tienes que pasarle **la ruta correcta**, yo supuse una ruta **app/media/imagenes/algo.png** . Otra opción es definir de forma explicita el lugar en el que la imagen está guardada para la función delete de la clase Storage:

```
public function destroy($id) {
  $vehiculo = Vehiculos::find($id);
  Storage::disk('public')->delete($vehiculo -> img_p_circulacion); 
  $vehiculo -> delete();
  return redirect() -> route('vehiculos.index');
}
```

El punto 2 es cosa de hacer un **chmod** si utilizas linux o modificar los permisos de la carpeta si utilizas windows ... pero si estás guardando la imagen de forma correcta dudo mucho que sean permisos.

El punto 3 es posible pero poco probable ... aún así uno nunca sabe XD

Comment: excelente amigo me sirvio! solo un tema yo no ocupaba el storage_path ocupaba el public_path y listo seria asi...

Comment: unlink(public_path('images_circulacion/'.$vehiculo -> img_p_circulacion));

Comment: Qué bien! Siempre un gusto ayudar =) y posiblemente a alguien le resulte útil en un futuro.

Comment: Si, Gracias!...